# MySQL: Getting value from column A that corresponds to MIN from column B

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have the following table:

```
 step_id    hospital_id     step_number     step_name
    17                  8            4          First Step
    18                  8            1          Second Step
    19                  8            2          Third Step
    20                  8            3          Finance Approval
```

What I am trying to do is get the step_id that corresponds to the smallest step number. So in the example above I am looking for step_id 18.

After looking over many posts I have been trying variations of the following to no avail:

```
SELECT `step_id`
    FROM `progress_steps`
    WHERE `hospital_id` = 8
    GROUP BY `step_id`
    HAVING MIN(`step_number`)
```

It seems to have worked for other but the above returns all rows from the example and other variations I have tried give me step_id 17 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   hospital_id = 8
ORDER   BY  step_number ASC
LIMIT   1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdd7b/1)

or if you want to get multiple rows having the same lowest `step_number`, use subquery:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   step_Number =
    (
        SELECT  step_Number
        FROM    tableName
        WHERE   hospital_id = 8
        ORDER   BY  step_number ASC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdd7b/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with duplicate record*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a82b/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
SELECT `step_id`
FROM `progress_steps`
WHERE `hospital_id` = 8
Order BY `step_id` 
LIMIT 1
```